# Will a PHP value travel through an include and then through a linked php stylesheet?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a index.php page, which has a header.php page included in it, which references a style.php file.

The page I am working on has the following in the head:

```
<?php
$page = "testimonials";
include 'header.php';
?>
```

The header.php has `if` statements to set the correct style sheets and variables for the nav bar etc and also includes as I said, the style.php sheet using the following code:

```
<link href="style.php"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css">
```

My question is, I am trying to use an `if` statement in style.php as below:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");     
if ($page == testimonials){
        print "margin-top: 5%;\n";
        }
?>
```

The `if` statement does not seem to be working however as this is not being printed, and I am wondering if this is because I can't pull the value through the include, then through the stylesheet `href`?

Thinking about it, I think that as stylesheets are not included like .php files, this may be the reason, could someone just confirm this is the case, or suggest a better work around?

I was thinking of perhaps putting some CSS in the `<head>` of the PHP `include` for my file under an `if` statement, but I feel that may not be best practice.

Comment: If that is your real code you have a syntax error that PHP should be warning you about and is probably causing your issue. Turn on error reporting and show all errors to see it.

Comment: ^^ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, at the top of your script, always when developing code (or enable in php.ini)

Comment: wrap testimonials in quotes if ($page == "testimonials") ....

Comment: Not a syntax error so much as a common sloppy style PHP will attempt to overcome (while issuing a notice) - and in this case will successfully overcome because the undefined constant `testimonials` will be treated as the expected string `'testimonials'`

Comment: Hi John,Thanks for your immediate response. I'm afraid my software shows no syntax error here. Are you able to elaborate where the error is. I'm using Komodo Editor and the above code pasted straight in produces no errors under php developer?

Comment: Why is `testimonials` not in quotes?

Comment: Easiest way to debug this is to put print_r("Current page is: ".$page); in the second file;

Comment: Graeme, it's worth pinging individuals using their at-handle, thus: @JohnConde (you have tab completion here too!). That will ensure a specific user sees your message.

Comment: @halfer thanks for intro advice

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I've used the code Michael provided and can see it's complaining about the testimonials being undefined. Thanks

Comment: @NickJ I didn't use quotes for my if statements in the rest of my code and had no problems (probably sloppy code being overcome as mentioned by Michael above), I was following a tutorial and seemed to be the way, perhaps changes needed across the board, but have put in quotes, still showing as undefined, I am doubting I can pull it in, as it's not actually sitting inside my document like a php include would?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this .... the link element is not an actual server side include. If you want to give the style.php file access to the variable in the header.php page, pass it via the query-string to the style.php page in the `link` tag.

```
<link href="style.php?page=<?=$page?>"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css">
```

Then in the style.php page, read the value from the query-string parameter:

```
<?
$page = $_GET['page'];
?>
```

Then, you can use it in an if statement inside the style.php page:

```
if ($page == 'testimonials'){
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you include some file, it is the same, as if you write the code from that file there, instead of include.

Your Problem is this:

```
if ($page == testimonials){
```

It should be

```
if ($page == 'testimonials'){
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, should include the '' but this is a linked file not included. Thanks for help and advice.